# Intellij IDEA doesn't recompile/rebuild angular2 project

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

*Before* after pressing Ctrl+S Angular2 project was always being rebuilt. *Now* absolutely no reactions even if I press

> Build -> Rebuild project

in event log I have always `"All files are up-to-date"` even when in files were a lot of changes.

I have updated Intellij IDEA version to 2016.3.5. 
When I run old projects they are rebuilding after pressing Ctrs+S, so I believe smth in initial configuration of project changed. But what exactly..?
Don't think it is nessessary but my version of angular2: 2.4.9.

Comment: what OS are you on? Is your application bundled with Webpack? do you use Webpack? When using it on Windows, it’s recommended to disable the IDE Safe write feature ( 'Use "safe write" in Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings), otherwise, the app won’t be updated on-time on changes. This issue is fixed in Webpack 2

Comment: `Build -> Rebuild project ` doesn't start webpack build/typescript compiler/etc. This command does nothing for Angular project